# MKMapView how to change the User Nearest location pin image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I want to change user nearest location pin image in map view.

"In my Project i show the some of the shop locations in map view. The locations (lat,long) are get from the api. Here i changed the given location pin image. it works fine. but i need to change the user nearest location pin image in the map view. I already get the distance details from the user current location to given api locations in that which are the locations are below 5 miles that location pin images are need to change.   "

Here is my Annotation Code:

// View for Annotation Delegate Code for changing the pin image.

```
     -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {

[self.annotationCustom_View removeFromSuperview];
[self.annotationCurrentLoc_View removeFromSuperview];

static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
CustomMapViewAnnotation * annotationView = (CustomMapViewAnnotation *)[self.locationsMap_View dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!annotationView)
{
    annotationView = [[CustomMapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LocationsYour-Current-Location-Icon"];    // User Current Location Image
    }
    else
    {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        for(int i=0;i<[locations_ArrayList count];i++)
        {
                MapViewLocationModel *objValue=[locations_ArrayList objectAtIndex:i];

            float value = [objValue.kiosk_distance floatValue];
                if(value < 5.0)
                {

                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LocationsFridge-Location-Icon"];    // Change the pin image which are the below 5.0 miles distance from the user current locations

                }
                else
                {
                    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LocationsBlackDot"];     // given api locations pin images
                }
        }


    });
        }
}

annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

return annotationView;

    }
```

This is my code. any one can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

> In order to display the pins in certain map area, first you need to
>   get the all pins inside the 5 miles.

```
 // 1. Set the map zoom area visible of 5 miles:

       mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
            centerCoordinate, 
            1609.344f * miles (5 in your case),
            1609.344f * miles (5 in your case)
        );

   //  2. Now get the Rect of this map area:

        MKMapRect mRect = self.map.visibleMapRect;

   //  3. Get the all pins inside this Rect:

        NSSet *annotationSet = [myMapView annotationsInMapRect:mRect];

        // print number of annotations
        NSLog(@"Number of annotations in rect: %d", annotationSet.count);

        // this will return an array from the NSSet
        NSArray *annotationArray = [annotationSet allObjects]; 

   //  4. Assign some parameter to this annotation, by taking some property in the annotation class.

   //  5. Now in your MapView Delegate method viewForAnnotation check the parameter and do the need full with the respective pins.
```

Hope this will help you to achieve what you want.